# Model deployment to managed online endpoints inside VNet in Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to deploy a model to a **managed** online endpoint in Azure Machine Learning.

(Along the lines of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-managed-online-endpoints).

This works fine with a publically accessible AML workspace, but not with our workspace inside our private VNET.

With an AML workspace/storage account in a private VNET the deployment fails:
[image]

I found that this is directly related to the network setting of the storage account. This is the setting that fails. Note that allowing Azure Services does not mitigate the problem:

[image]

Is this is blind spot of managed endpoints, which is simply not yet supported or is this a bug?

The problem can be reproduced with the sample code at
https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/tree/main/cli/endpoints/online/managed/sample
i.e.

```
az ml online-deployment create --name blue -f endpoints/online/managed/sample/blue-deployment.yml
```

The 'troubleshooting' guide in the error message refers to the importance of accessibility of the storage account (and Azure Container Registry), but does not consider the usecase, where AML is inside a private VNET:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-online-endpoints?tabs=cli#authorization-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If workspace and storage are private, you need to make egress_public_network_access flag disabled. This flag is required to establish private endpoint connections from managed online deployment to your private resources. Do not forget to approve PE connections.

Doc for Managed Online Endpoint network isolation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-secure-online-endpoint?tabs=model

Comment: Hi, I had tried egress_public_network_access already, but the problem occurs already during creation of the deployment.
Since today I am getting another error message however: 'Managed Vnet deployment requires Premium Tier ACR' - The linked Container Rehistry is however, already set to Premium.

Comment: It works with a newly created workspace, but not with an older workspace. For the older workspace I changed SKU of ACR to Premium, but I still get the message 'Managed Vnet deployment requires Premium Tier ACR'. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Ok, I had to create another premium ACR and link it to the AML workspace.